# pheatmap r- annotation legend not showing all values

Tags: r, pheatmap

when drawing annotation, not all of the clusters are shown (only 4 out of 8). How can I solve it and see all the colors with their names?
Thanks!
[image]

The data is a correlation map (cor_martix), that I extracted the clusters that created by pheatmap, and make an annotation from them.

code:

```
chosen_k = 4 
res = pheatmap(mat = cor_martix, breaks=seq(-1, 1, length.out=101))

myannotation = as.data.frame(cutree(res$tree_row,k = chosen_k)) #extract k clusters
names(myannotation)[1] = "cluster" 
palette1 <- rainbow(chosen_k,alpha = 0) #make colors
ann_colors = list (cluster = palette1) #make annotation colors
pheatmap(mat = cor_martix, breaks=seq(-1, 1, length.out=101),annotation_col =  myannotation, annotation_colors =ann_colors)
```

Comment: What is the code you used ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem.

```
library(pheatmap)
chosen_k = 8 

# Generate correlation matrix
X <- matrix(rnorm(100*28), nrow=100)
colnames(X) <- paste0("x",1:ncol(X))  
cor_matrix <- cor(X)
```

First, when generating the `myannotation` data frame, the `cluster` column must be defined as a factor.

```
myannotation <- as.data.frame(cutree(res$tree_row, k = chosen_k))
names(myannotation)[1] = "cluster" 
myannotation$cluster <- factor(myannotation$cluster, levels=1:chosen_k, 
                               labels=paste0("Clu", 1:chosen_k))
```

Then, when defining the `ann_colors` list with annotation colors, each color must be associated to the corresponding cluster name.

```
palette1 <- rainbow(chosen_k, alpha=.5) #make colors
names(palette1) <- levels(myannotation$cluster)   
ann_colors <- list(cluster = palette1)
```

Now the annotation legend shows the right number of colors.

```
pheatmap(mat = cor_matrix, breaks=seq(-1, 1, length.out=101), 
         annotation_col=myannotation, annotation_colors=ann_colors)
```

[image]